# 'str' object has no attribute 'get' in Tkinter callback

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to trace an OptionMenu widget's choice so that different choices run a different function. However, I keep running into the error below:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "-", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "-", line 149, in callback
    self.bookingCanvas(optVar)
  File "-", line 152, in bookingCanvas
    perfDate = optVar.get()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
    optVar = StringVar(self.root)
    optVar.trace('r', callback=self.callback)
    optVar.set("06/10/20") # default value
    optMenu_Label = Label(self.root, text='Select a performance date:',bg='gray15', fg='yellow', relief=GROOVE)
    optMenu_Label.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=15, pady=15)

    optMenu = OptionMenu(self.root, optVar, '04/10/20','5/10/20','6/10/20')
    optMenu.pack(side=TOP,anchor=NW, padx=35, pady=3)
```

The callback of the .trace() above:

```
    def callback(self, optVar, *args):
    print("SOMETHING HAS CHANGED")
    self.bookingCanvas(optVar)
```

The error area (I assume):

```
    def bookingCanvas(self, optVar):
        perfDate = optVar.get()
        print("This is a Date >>>",perfDate)
        print("did we get here?")
```

Comment: `self.callback` is a `str`, and strings do not have a `.get()` object.

Comment: The `optVar` in `callback()` is not the same thing as the `optVar` you created - it will just be the internal name of the `StringVar`, not the actual `StringVar` object itself.

Comment: Change to `def callback(self, option, *args):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback from a trace is given the *name* of the variable, not a reference to the variable object. The name is a string, which is why you're getting the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'`.

With the name, you can use the common widget method `getvar` to get the value stored in the variable.

In your definition of `callback` you can get the value and pass it to your function like so: (assuming for this example that you have a global variable named 'root` which represents the root widget)

```
def callback(self, optVar_name, *args):
    print("SOMETHING HAS CHANGED")
    value = root.getvar(optVar_name)
    self.bookingCanvas(value)
```

With that, you can remove the call to `get` in `bookingCanvas`:

```
def bookingCanvas(self, perfDate):
    print("This is a Date >>>",perfDate)
    print("did we get here?")
```